# Graph estimated parameters from a set of estimated distributions

Tags: r, dataset

I have estimated a set of distributions through grouping the data on time period and gender using the following code:

```
df.weibull <- tapply(df$attribute, list(time=df$time, gender=df$gender), fitdist, "weibull")
```

I would like to graph the scale parameter of these distributions over time, with a separate line for each gender. I know I can access an individual scale parameter by:

```
df.weibull[1,"M"][[1]]$estimate["scale"]
```

but I cannot figure out how to access all the scale parameters at once in a direct manner. Solutions to either access all the parameters or how to write the original function to return a more accessible data structure are fine.

EDIT: Here is some code that reproduces the data structure:

```
 gender.df <- c("M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F")
 time.df <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
 attribute.df <- c(10,20,30,11,21,31,45,55,65,1,2,3)
 df <- data.frame(attribute.df,time.df,gender.df)
 names(df) <- c("attribute", "time", "gender")
 library(fitdistrplus)
 df.weibull <- tapply(df$attribute, list(time=df$time, gender=df$gender), fitdist, "weibull")
```

Comment: Could you provide a section of your dataset?

Comment: Added as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to fit a Weibull distribution by `gender` and `time` groups. I suppose that this is just a tiny subsection of your dataset because you have just 3 observations per group. How about:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
sumdf <- setDT(df)[, as.list(fitdist(attribute, dist= "weibull")$estimate), by = .(time, gender)]

   time gender    shape     scale
1:    1      M 2.738085 22.587353
2:    2      M 2.893080 23.666143
3:    1      F 7.793204 58.553205
4:    2      F 2.738652  2.258509
```

Then you could plot e.g.:

```
ggplot(sumdf) + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = scale, col = gender))
```

Or

```
ggplot(sumdf) + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = shape, col = gender))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This works, but seems computationally intensive. As if I wanted to then create a graph for the shape parameter as well, I would need to re-estimate all the distributions instead of accessing the information from a data structure. While this does generate the graph, I would be interested to know if there is another way.

Comment: See the edit above. Both shape and scale are stored in the grouped data frame.Then you could plot either with the desired tool. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, that is quite a bit more usable. Thanks!